# Custom Module for Custom Column using Plugin Yes/No option

Tags: module, uicomponent, plugin, system.xml, magento-2.2.5

I have been digging all day trying to figure out a way to enable/disable the plugins of my custom module with system configuration yes/no. Basically, I have a custom module that adds the Company Column to all Admin Order Grids as well as Customer Grids.

I have created the system.xml file to display the options on the backend, including an option to disable the entire module or just certain Order Grids (Order, Invoice, Shipment, etc).

system.xml:

```
<system>
    <tab id="trucatch" translate="label" sortOrder="500">
        <label><![CDATA[Trucatch]]></label>
    </tab>
    <section id="companycolumn" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label><![CDATA[Company Column]]></label>
        <tab>trucatch</tab>
        <resource>Trucatch_CompanyColumn::companycolumn</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General</label>
            <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label>Enabled</label><source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                <comment><![CDATA[Enable to allow Company Column on Sales Grids]]></comment>
            </field>
            <field id="order_grid_enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label>Show on Order Grid</label><source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                <comment><![CDATA[]]></comment>
                <depends>
                    <field id="*/*/enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>

**Additional Information**

            <field id="invoice_grid_enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label>Show on Invoice Grid</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                <comment><![CDATA[]]></comment>
                <depends>
                    <field id="*/*/enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>

**End Additional Information**

        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

config.xml:

```
<default>
    <companycolumn>
        <general>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
            <order_grid_enabled>1</order_grid_enabled>

**Additional Information**

            <invoice_grid_enabled>1</invoice_grid_enabled>

**End Additional Information**

        </general>
    </companycolumn>
</default>
```

di.xml is calling all the plugins.

Sample:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin 
        name="sales_order_additional_columns" 
        type="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection" 
        sortOrder="100" 
        disabled="false" 
    />

**Additional Information**

    <plugin 
        name="sales_invoice_additional_columns" 
        type="RLTcode\CompanyColumn\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesInvoiceGridCollection" 
        sortOrder="100" 
        disabled="false" 
    />

**End Additional Information**

</type>
```

I have also created a Helper\Data.php file to check, but I have not been able to associate that with the actual plugin file. Or am I looking in the wrong place and this needs to be implemented in the layout/ui_component files?

Data.php

```
namespace Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
/**
 * Config path to enable/disable module
 */
const CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_ENABLE_MODULE = 'companycolumn/general/enabled';

/**
 * Config path to enable/disable module
 */
const CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_ORDER_GRID = 'companycolumn/general/order_grid_enabled';


**Additional Information**

/**
 * Config path to enable/disable module
 */
const CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_INVOICE_GRID = 'companycolumn/general/invoice_grid_enabled';

**End Additional Information**


protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_ENABLE_MODULE,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}

public function isOrderGridEnabled()
{
    return (bool) $this->getConfigValue(
        self::CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_ORDER_GRID,
        \Magenot\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}


**Additional Information**

public function isInvoiceGridEnabled()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_INVOICE_GRID,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}

**End Additional Information**
```

AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection.php:

```
<?php 

namespace Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Plugin;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
private $resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function aroundGetReport(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName
) {
    $result = $proceed($requestName);
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection) {
            $select = $result->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['soa1' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa1.parent_id AND soa1.address_type = "billing"',
                ['billing_company' => 'company']
            );
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['soa2' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa2.parent_id AND soa2.address_type = "shipping"',
                ['shipping_company' => 'company']
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

** **Additional Information** **

AddColumnsSalesInvoiceGridCollection.php

```
<?php 

namespace Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Plugin;

class AddColumnsSalesInvoiceGridCollection
{
private $resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function aroundGetReport(

\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName
) {
    $result = $proceed($requestName);
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection) {
            $select = $result->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['soa1' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa1.parent_id AND soa1.address_type = "billing"',
                ['billing_company' => 'company']
            );
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['soa2' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa2.parent_id AND soa2.address_type = "shipping"',
                ['shipping_company' => 'company']
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

** **End Additional Information** **

And Lastly the sales_order_grid.xml: (Added the solution from @kunj below)

```
<!-- "sales_order_grid_data_source" -->
<columns name="sales_order_columns">

    <!-- sales_order_address billing_company -->
    <column name="billing_company" class="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bill-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <!-- sales_order_address shipping_company -->
    <column name="shipping_company" class="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>
```

** **Additional Information** **

sales_order_invoice_grid.xml

```
<!-- "sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source" -->
<columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">

    <!-- sales_order_address billing_company -->
    <column name="billing_company" class="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Company2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bill-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <!-- sales_order_address shipping_company -->
    <column name="shipping_company" class="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Company2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>
```

** **End Additional Information** **

I am looking to be able to enable/disable certains aspects of this module. For instance you could disable the Company Column from the Sales Order Grid (all information associated with that is above). But I can't seem to grasp how to implement it into my plugins, if it is even possible.

I do understand that you can hide columns and such in Magento2 but I thought this would be an easy way to implement it as well. This way it would not load them for Filters also, but I am still working on getting the Filtering to work.

Please let me know if you need anything else to better assist me.

** **Additional Information** **

I have added the answer provided by @kunj to my post above. Besides the Company.php file which you can see in the answer. As well I have added another bit of information which handles the Company Name on the Invoice Grid.

** **End Additional Information** **

Comment: Is there a way to change `disabled="false"` to `disabled="true"` in the di.xml with the Yes/No feature from the system.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it is working for me :

```
    <!-- sales_order_address billing_company -->
    <column name="billing_company" class="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bill-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <!-- sales_order_address shipping_company -->
    <column name="shipping_company"  class="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>
```

Now we need to disable component based on our configuration in `Company.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Kunj
 */

namespace Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;


class Company  extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param \Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Helper\Data $configData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    private $configData;

    public function __construct(
        \Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Helper\Data $configData,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->configData = $configData;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        $myData = ((!$this->configData->isOrderGridEnabled()))?['visible' => "0",'componentDisabled'=>"1"]:['visible' => "1",'componentDisabled'=>"0"];
        foreach ($myData as $field => $value)
        {
            $config[$field] = (bool)$value;
        }
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
        parent::prepare();
    }

}
```

Above code will remove field if set NO in configuration and below code will display field but with the blank value.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kunj
 */

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Plugin;


class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $resource;

    private $data;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data $data
    ) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        if (($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') &&($this->data->isOrderGridEnabled())) {
            if ($result instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection) {
                $select = $result->getSelect();
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ['soa1' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                    'main_table.entity_id = soa1.parent_id AND soa1.address_type = "billing"',
                    ['billing_company' => 'company']
                );
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ['soa2' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                    'main_table.entity_id = soa2.parent_id AND soa2.address_type = "shipping"',
                    ['shipping_company' => 'company']
                );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent Option 1 is working perfectly! Thank you. I did have to make a slight change in my Data.php file in order for this to work as I was receiving a few errors but now it's good to go! Can you please advise how to incorporate the `isEnabled()` as well? Currently it is just hiding all other fields in admin. I have multiple other functions in my Data.php that I need to incorporate as well `isInvoiceGridEnabled()`.

Comment: Welcome!, happy to help, please elaborate about method query?

Comment: if `isEnabled()` is disabled all others functions for the module are disabled. Additional functions in Data.php are `isInvoiceGridEnabled()`, `isShipmentGridEnabled()`, and about 10 others which display the column in all admin grids. So I would need an array in Company.php to possibly check all functions in Data.php rather than just `isOrderGridEnabled`. Not sure if that answers your request. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to display same filed in the different grid then you can add all method condition in the same place. I would suggest you make each file for each grid.

Comment: Please accpet answer and click on +50,  it will help to other developer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help. So you would recommend duplicating the Company.php file for every function I have in the Data.php file? And just replace `isOrderGridEnabled` with the other functions?

Comment: @RLTcode, Not sure about your requirement but as per my understanding yes, I would suggest you create a new file for each function and great because it will help you in future if you will have any customization for any gird.

Comment: I have added additional information which I am using to add the Company Column to the Invoice Grid. Are you recommending that I add a `Company2.php` to handle the Invoice Grid function (like I have noted on the `sales_order_invoice_grid.xml`)? Also how can I incorporate the `isEnabled()` ? Basically if `isEnabled` is turned off on the backend all others are disabled as well.

Comment: Nevermind, I just created additional Ui Component files and it is working fine. I had to make an adjustment in Data.php in order for isEnabled() to cancel all others if turned off. The only thing I am stuck on now is how to use the system config setting to hide the column in Customer -> Orders Tab Grid. I add the column by extending Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/Orders.php but I can't figure out how to check the Data.php file and then send a forwardNoRoute possibly?